# Special word for death anniversary

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a special word for a death anniversary? For example a birth anniversary would be a "birthday", but what would a death anniversary be?

Comment: Its a 'death anniversary'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_anniversary).

Comment: In Roman Catholic tradition, a saint's Feast Day is their day of death (cause that's when they went to heaven). The term _feast day_ is not in use for ordinary people, afaik -- only saints.

Comment: Also Catholic, but for anyone - the _month's mind_ is the month-iversary of their death. _The anniversary of their death_ is what's used for the year; the phrase is in the Mass.

Comment: @tmgr Some of us use "year's mind".

Comment: @AndrewLeach The combination did occur to me while writing the comment, but, in truth, I don't think I've actually heard it myself. Glad to know it exists!

Comment: Like @tmgr, I am very familiar with a month’s mind and an ‘anniversary mass’ but not a year’s mind. BTW not sure if month’s mind is a international Catholic thing or a Irish Catholic thing.

Answer (score 6):

The word for a death anniversary is... **anniversary**.

> **anniversary** *noun* an·ni·ver·sa·ry | \ˌa-nə-ˈvərs-rē,-ˈvər-sə-\
>
> the annual recurrence of a date marking a notable event

In the instance of a death, you would modify it with a prepositional expression. An example would be:

> *There are plans to release a film about his life next year, which would mark the tenth anniversary of his death.*

We usually associate anniversary with marriages or work tenure, but the term is etymologically agnostic to those distinctions. Much like there isn't a special word for "sports car" (outside of the actual names of cars, like Ferrari, or Lamborghini); it's just a *car* that's intended for the sport of driving.

English has not accommodated in wide use any of the other answers suggested so far (deathday*, deathiversary, heavenly birthday, yahrzeit). [*deathday, is a lazy portmanteau. Its history only attests to its obsolescence, and [it is in the bottom 20% of looked-up words](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deathday), and [an uncommon expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deathday&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeathday%3B%2Cc0). ]

Comment: Exactly. None of the proposed terms are commonly used, regardless of Christian denomination or branch of Judaism.

Comment: "'_deathday_ is a lazy portmanteau"? Like "birthday"? Hardly legitimate criticism. I agree _anniversary_ is the most commonly-used word and the right answer and upvoted for those reasons but _deathday_ has certainly had plenty of use, as a [Google Books search](//www.google.com/search?q=%22deathday%22&biw=1368&bih=758&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=rzLHW-yQFNH7kwX1_4SIDQ&start=190&sa=N) shows. Perhaps there was more use for a shorter term in times of higher church attendance. Bit harsh, all round.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's rating for looked-up words is only a measure of how many people have looked it up, and says little about its actual frequency of _appearance_ in the wild. Just because a number of people can't remember what the meaning of a word is doesn't mean it is uncommon.

Comment: That said, 'anniversary (of  death)' is the most natural way of saying the concept the OP is describing.

Comment: I think it doesn't actually answer the question. You have to add extra information to the word "anniversary" in order to be clear, so it's not one word that clearly means what the OP asked for. A 
 Also, the fact that deathday is uncommon doesn't say anything about the word's suitability in describing something. Amortise isn't that common, we usually say "pay off (mortgage)". Also about the lazy portmanteau point, if it's lazy I think words like "stopgap" and "unfriend" are rather lazy too, though very well accepted. Sorry for all the criticism, just giving my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

One word for this is **deathday** (a word which dates back to Old English, in fact):

> the day or the anniversary of the day of a person's death.
>   <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deathday) Unabridged. Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018</sub>

One well-known example is the deathday party that Nearly Headless Nick has (*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter 8: "The Deathday Party").

Comment: +1 because "deathday" is the logical antonym of "birth+day", it has its own dictionary entry, and it's easy enough to remember.

Comment: I  have never seen this one anywhere ever. But I that it is in the dictionary. Funny thing, usage is one thing; dictionary entries another...

Comment: I have never heard anyone use this ever, and it sounds horrible. Where I come from we say 'anniversary'.

Answer (score 2):

In informal contexts, the word that's generally used is **deathiversary** (also sometimes spelled [death-iversary](http://fourtwonine.com/2017/01/10/david-bowies-one-year-death-iversary-heres-weve-missed/)):

> the anniversary of someone's death
>
> *I am eating neapolitan ice cream all day today in honor of my dad's 2 year deathiversary.*
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=deathiversary) (definition by Miss Jaimie)</sub>

Although the entry on UD doesn't have a lot of upvotes, the word is easy to understand. It's also fairly widespread. Here are some examples:

- [5 Ideas for Facing Deathiversaries - Modern Loss](https://modernloss.com/5-ideas-for-deathiversaries/)
- [Aggronautix Unveils GG Allin 25th Deathiversary Bust - PopHorror](https://www.pophorror.com/aggronautix-gg-allin-deathiversary-bust/)
- [Shakespeare's 400th “Deathiversary”: His Best Death Scenes Ever](https://www.sjpl.org/blog/shakespeare%E2%80%99s-400th-%E2%80%9Cdeathiversary%E2%80%9D-his-best-death-scenes-ever)
- #deathiversary on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/hashtag/deathiversary)
- Results in [Google News](https://www.google.com/search?q="deathiversary"&tbm=nws)
- Assorted Google Books examples:

  - > Every year, he hated this deathiversary more. ([Cypress Hollow Boxed Set](https://books.google.com/books?id=JuDmDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT400&dq="deathiversary".))
  - > Les, Happy five-week deathiversary. ([Losing Hope](https://books.google.com/books?id=buawWCOpbLsC&pg=PT41&dq="deathiversary".))
  - > “What about on the Deathiversary? Ooooohweeee. Look out!” Buddy exclaimed. ([The King Is Dead](https://books.google.com/books?id=tLKtlwJYe0sC&pg=PT182&dq="deathiversary".))

Comment: I see the top definition on Urban Dictionary was posted in 2007 but has only received confirmation by **6** visitors, whilst the second definition has 12 thumbs up but also four thumbs down, which suggests that the term, *deathiversary*, is extremely rare. I would *still* not recommend it to non-native speakers.

Comment: This sounds ... horrible.

Comment: This is not a word in wide use

Comment: The Urban Dictionary suffers horribly from urban mythology. But even so, it is pretty horrible but very useful to see these usages. The idea that any  single answer to this question would cover the entirety of what one could say about it is just silly. So, thank you Laurel. I now know what to eschew. :)

Comment: It may grate like nails down a phonic blackboard (and in its singular lack of solemnity) but people say it - and even write and publish it - as this answer shows. I'm convinced. What else does it take to make a word?

Answer (score 1):

The only word I know that matches this is very specific:

> [yahrzeit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yahrzeit)

(pronunced 'yar tsayt' = /'jar tsait/) is an anniversary of someone's death, usually a close relative. But it is specifically used only in the context of a Ashkenazi Jewish memorial. The word is from Yiddish (close to German) for 'year time'.

There is no similarly on-point word in English for an anniversary of a death outside of the Jewish tradition.

Comment: Is this an English word? Is it commonly heard among AmEng speakers who are not of the Jewish faith?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it is an English word, borrowed from Yiddish. It is a word used by English speaking people when speaking English.  The particular people doing that are usually Ashkenazi Jews. It is on par with 'eucharist' for non-Catholics; it's 'inside-baseball' but those outside but nearby might have heard it in passing. Google for 'yahrzeit' and you'll see lots of hits in English sites describing Jewish practices.

Comment: I have never heard this word myself.  Maybe all my friends have been Sephardic or Ladino speakers. [joke]

Answer (score 0):

One term which is used, particularly in some forms of Christianity, is *heavenly birthday* — the day the person appeared in heaven — to contrast the day with the earthly birthday when they appeared on earth.

> If it was a birthday celebration, it was Christ's heavenly birthday, not his earthly one, which was being celebrated ...
>
> [*Revelation: from Metaphor to Analogy,* Richard Swinburne, 1992](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yhEAPsPQbMUC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22heavenly+birthday%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=Q5bGmodEGq&sig=MmOHICogaMGEQ5fDz_fICoZxBy8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXp_i_6O3ZAhXLBsAKHSjYB6YQ6AEIbzAM#v=onepage&q=%22heavenly%20birthday%22%20meaning&f=false)

> For example, young children may commemorate a sibling's ''heavenly birthday'' by lighting candles and sharing memories of the deceased.
>
> [*Children and Loss: a practical handbook,* Pomeroy/Garcia, 2012](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xrhjDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22heavenly+birthday%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=r6BRaTflAq&sig=yp7ZGTG-NMcgpbqmVzs80zYjd-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXp_i_6O3ZAhXLBsAKHSjYB6YQ6AEIgAEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22heavenly%20birthday%22%20meaning&f=false)

> The Assumption is important to many Catholic and Orthodox Christians as the Virgin Mary's heavenly birthday (the day that Mary was received into Heaven).
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assumption_of_Mary)

This wouldn't necessarily be appropriate for in all religions, and not all branches of Christianity either. And humanists would disagree about an afterlife at all.

Comment: See my comment under Laurel's answer. This is one more piece that can be used to answer this question.

Comment: A theological quibble: in Catholicism it's _at least_ an open doctrinal question whether Mary _died_ when received into heaven. I, for one, was taught in school that she did not. Only pointing this out as the exceptional circumstances of Mary's death or non-death has a direct bearing on the relevance of the last example sentence!